# Remove duplicates from array of Int in Swift (for-in-loop)

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates, for-in-loop

There are a lot of methods to remove duplicates from an array in swift, but I'm trying to use a **for in loop** to manage that. 
Can any one explain, why this code doesn't work?

> Fatal error: Index out of range

```
func deleteDuplicates(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var newArray = array

    for i in 0 ..< newArray.count - 1  {
        for j in i + 1 ..< newArray.count  {

            if newArray[i] == newArray[j] {
                newArray.remove(at: j)
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray
}

array1 = [0, 1, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 7, 11, 4, 5, 5, 8]
deleteDuplicates(array: array1)
```

Comment: Your's nested loop causing this crash.

Comment: A better approach here is to loop over `array` and adding values in the loop instead to `newArray`

Comment: This should do it : `func deleteDuplicates(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return Array(NSOrderedSet(array: array)) as? [Int] ?? array
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic part is to iterate over an array and update that array at the same time. In this case, removing an element while iterating.

Removing an element decreases array length (`count`) and also changes indices. Therefore in

```
for j in i + 1 ..< array.count  {
    if array[i] == array[j] {
        newArray.remove(at: j)
    }
}
```

After removing the first index, your other indices become invalid. Note that `count` is always read only once, before the actual iteration.

This is one of the reasons why removing elements during iteration is dangerous and complicated. You could fix it by maintaining the number of removed elements and update indices accordingly. Or you can iterate backwards:

```
var newArray = array

for i in (0 ..< newArray.count - 1).reversed()  {
    for j in (i + 1 ..< newArray.count).reversed()  {
        if newArray[i] == newArray[j] {
            newArray.remove(at: j)
        }
    }
}
return newArray
```

You are still changing indices and `count` but since you are iterating backwards, you only change the indices that have been already used.

In general it's simple and safer to build a new array instead of updating the current one:

```
var newArray: [Int] = []

for value in array {
    if !newArray.contains(value) {
       newArray.append(value)
    }
}

return newArray
```

which can be very reduced in complexity (performance) by using a `Set` to keep added elements:

```
var newArray: [Int] = []
var foundElements: Set<Int> = []

for value in array {
    if foundElements.insert(value).inserted {
       newArray.append(value)
    }
}

return newArray
```

Which can be simplified using `filter`:

```
var foundElements: Set<Int> = []
return array.filter { foundElements.insert($0).inserted }
```

Answer (score 0):

One Reason is you are modifying the same array on which you are running two for loops. To understand in details, use the debugger as Martin says. And

This can be done using one for loop and Set:

```
var newArray = [0, 1, 8, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 7, 11, 4, 5, 5, 8]
var array = Set<Int>()
for i in  newArray {
    array.insert(i)
}
print(array)
```

output:

```
[4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 8, 6, 11, 7]
```

Comment: What you are doing is incorrect. You are not keeping the original order.

Comment: @Sulthan, I understand. I showed a way to remove duplicates. OP didn't mention anything about keeping the order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple approach that you can try.

```
func removeDuplicates(_ nums: inout [Int]) {    
        var arrLen = nums.count
        var index = 0
        while(index < arrLen - 1){
            if nums[index] == nums[index+1] {
                nums.remove(at: index)
                arrLen = arrLen - 1
            }else{
                index = index+1
            }
        }
    }
```

It removes duplicates inplace without the need for new array being created.